# Magento: Programmatically Detect if Live/Production Site

Tags: magento

In Magento, is there a best practice way of detecting if live/production site (vs. development site)?  For example, only run debug code if on development site (do not run in production).

Comment: You *should* be running two separate installs with two separated databases ..  Live should never be in the same file structure as Dev (Staging) site.  And you should always separate your Dev Database from live as well so that **IF** you mess something up, file-wise or data-wise, your site never goes down, and no customers are lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing canonical, but Magento does have a "developer mode".  When Magento's in developer mode, raw errors are displayed and other debugging code that's not suitable for production is run.

There's nothing in Magento that forces "developer mode" in a live/production or development environment so you'll need to take care of this yourself.

Turning developer mode on:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
```

Turning developer mode off:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);
```

Checking the state of developer mode

```
if(Mage::getIsDeveloperMode())
{
    //put debugging code here.
}
```